# How to convert Binary string to Just Binary?

Tags: python, binary

I want to know how to convert binary string to just binary numbers.
For example, there is a data string as "0xC194"
I succeeded to get binary string from string through bin(data) format
And after, I want to shift a bit using 'data >> 8'
But it shows error that data is string which couldn't shift the bit

How can I convert binary string to just binaries for shifting bits ?

```
data = "0xC194"
data_b = bin(data)
print(data_b)              // 0b1100000110010100
data_b = data_b >> 8       
print(data_b)              // error
```

Comment: `int('0xC194', 16)`…?

Comment: or just dont use quotes `0xC194`